# Given integers $a$ and $b$ prove that if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ for which $ax + by = (a, b)$, then $(x, y) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I know that the answer involves Bezout's theorem in some way.
I tried this:

Let $(a, b) = d$
Let $a = dk_1 and b = dk_2$
So, $ax + by = d$ becomes $dk_1x + dk_2x = d$
Dividing by d, we get:
$k_1x + k_2x = 1$
So, $(x,y) = 1$
Is this sufficient?

Comment: Yes: this proof is ok.

Comment: No, it is not OK. There is no $y$ involved. $k_1x+k_2x=(k_1+k_2)x=1$ does not imply $(x,y)=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote x instead of y. It will be correct then, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prove it in the following way:

Let $(a,b)=d$. By definition, there exists $q_1,q_2$ such that $a=dq_1, b=dq_2$. Then, by hypothesis, $ax + by = dq_1x + dq_2y = d$. As we are in an integral domain, we can simplify the expression to $q_1x + q_2y=1$. Now, notice that you directly concluded that (x,y)=1. This is only true in the case that a linear combination of integers is equal to 1 (or unity, if we were working with polynomials in $\Bbb K[x]$).

By definition of gcd, we say $d'=(x,y)$. Then, $d$ has to divide 1, because $q_1x + q_2y=1$. Hence, the only possibility is $(x,y)=1$.